# Using asp.net mvc 3 + Razor with Ajax and jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax, razor

I'm trying to make the "Google Instant" like experience (I'm not looking for Auto-complete).

Google instant is the dynamically change the "search result" as you type (not the suggestions, which can be achieved with auto complete).

The page will simply have a text input control, in which as your type, you get result below the text input control.

I know, I must make some async calls on "onKeyPress": So first how can I do that in jquery?

Second, any good tutorials on combining asp.net MVC with Razor and Ajax?

edited: as people were confusing auto-complete with instant result

Answer (score 1):

The term that you should use is  'autocomplete'

Have a look at the link below:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

It's server independant. Basically, on the server side, you must create a service, given a string return the possible values that relate to that string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'm not looking for auto complete. What I'm looking is actually called "google instant" (at least by google), its updating of actual search result as I type I'm looking for. Second, for true mvc the view should only interact with the control, control can route the request to\get data from model (which might a service). Any idea about, I think a basic tutorial on how to make an ajax call in on some event and update the content of a section of the page is called I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great article here on how to create an instant search with Jquery, PHP and HTML

http://woorkup.com/2010/09/13/how-to-create-your-own-instant-search/

The one caveat I encountered was that you need to put the Javscript code inside a

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
/*Your JS Instant Search goes here */
});
```

which wasn't clear from the article.

For ASP.NET MVC 3, create a controller/action that returns a JSON or JSONP object. If you're a beginner, this might trip you up as you will get CrossSiteJson errors. This link will help:

[Ajax json post to Controller across domains, "not allowed by" Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547672/ajax-json-post-to-controller-across-domains-not-allowed-by-access-control-all)

From doing these two, I was able to do the instant search in MVC3 and it works really well.
Using Firebug or WebKit Web Inspector and Fiddler really helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is still a variant of autocomplete, if you break it down:

1. Fire autocomplete on key presses.
2. Fire Ajax search on autocomplete success/load (whatever the event might be).

Writing number 2 is minimal work for you unless somebody has written a plugin that does both. It's a nice little project - write a plugin that combines a text box and div and does autosearch.