# Sending JSON from one asp.net web application to another

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-development-serv

My solution contains two asp.net MVC projects. One is going to be a web-service, another a normal website, getting data from beforementioned web-service.

I have the following method in my web-service home controller:

```
...
public JSONResult GetTeacher(){
   return JSON(new {TeacherName = this.teacher.name });
}
```

I'm trying to access this method from the other web-application(which is going to be the website) by using this $.ajax method :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'localhost:11370/Home/GetTeacher',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        $('#results').html('Welcome, ' + response.Name);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

When I start debugging my solution it opens up two web-development servers, both on different ports. As a result, when the $.ajax call happens I get a popup with this information:

```
the page at localhost:11510 says:
"readystate":0, "responsetext": "" , "status":0, "statustext":"error"
```

When I try running the script directly in the google chrome console I get the following message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:11370/Home/GetTeacher. 
Origin http://localhost:11510 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Any help on how to actually access the method with $.ajax would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I also tried making a simple html file to see what would happen if I would make the call to the web-service. Same result. Also, when I just type in the url to the method, it works fine and displays the name of the teacher.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the [`same origin policy restriction`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) that's built in browsers you cannot send cross domain AJAX requests. One possible workaround is to use [`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) but since not all browsers support it yet, if you want a cross browser solution you may consider using [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

You may take a look at [`this custom JsonpResult`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7547814/29407) I wrote to illustrate how you could consume your controller action from a different domain. It is important to note that jQuery's JSONP implementation works only with GET requests. You cannot POST to a controller action cross domain. If you need to do that the only reliable way to achieve this would be to write a server side script on the home domain that will act as a bridge between the 2 domains. Then you would send the AJAX request to this new script that will delegate the request to the remote domain and return the result.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not really that concerned for cross-browser compatibility, because the result will be used in an iOS app.

Comment: Great, then you could use [`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Simply set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header inside your `GetTeacher` controller action.